# Visual Studio 2012 VB.NET Can't exit Windows Form After Using Combobox

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vb.net-2010

O.K. I'll apologize right up front because this one is WEIRD and very hard to explain, but I have to try...

I created a Windows Form that has ten or so bound sub-forms (Tab Control) for entering data. I recently figured out how to get the ComboBox fields to allow selection from other tables also within the MDB file (originated from Access 2012).

What's so strange is that when I run the form, it works beautifully until I use the dropdown to select a value. The value gets selected, but after that, no mouse clicks within the form, including the red eXit button. I can click the VS2012 red Stop Debugging square to stop running the form, but nothing else responds to mouse or keyboard input ***except within the ComboBox text***.

My best guess is there is some kind of endless loop occurring associated with the ComboBox's lose focus event.

How anyone ever experienced this before, and if so, what did you do to correct the problem?

I would be happy to post a video demonstrating this strange behavior if someone can advise me how to do so on the SO forum.

Thanks,
Tony G.

Comment: If one of the SO admins could kindly explain to me why a question would be downvoted, it would help me to do better in the future. I can certainly understand a poorly written (or even incorrect) answer, but not a question.

Answer (score 0):

I thought perhaps this problem was being caused by my LINQ query, but ultimately solved the problem by upgrading VS2013 to Update #5.